# Loop through folder of images and show images one by one

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm new to c# and WPF and trying to build an application that loops through a folder and show's the images inside one by one. When the last one is shown it needs to show the first one again.

I tried naming all the files 1.jpg , 2.jpg and so on, and then just loop through the amount of pictures. But if I delete one then it gives an error.

Is there a better way to acomplish this ?

I'm using C# and a WPF window with an image inside a grid.

Any help would be greatly appriciated!

edit: current code

```
private string[] files;
    private System.Timers.Timer timer;

    private int counter;
    private int Imagecounter;

    public IntroScreen()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(this.MainWindow_Loaded);
    }

    private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        setupPics();
    }



    private void setupPics() 
    {
        timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Tick);
        timer.Interval = (2000);
        timer.Enabled = true;
        timer.Start();

        files = Directory.GetFiles("../../Resources/Taken/", "*.jpg", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
        Imagecounter = files.Length;
        counter = 0;
    }

    private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        counter++;

       Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Input, new ThreadStart(() =>
            {
                Picture.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(files[counter - 1], UriKind.Relative));
            }));

       if (counter == Imagecounter)
       {
           counter = 0;
       }

    }
```

This isen't working, It finds the items in the folder, but the image doesn't change.

It doesn't return an error, the images just don't show up.

Anyone have any suggestions ?

Comment: What's the error? Are you trying to delete when you're iterating through the collection of images?

Comment: Well not really an error, but I count the amount of pictures in my folder and then loop from 1 till the end. but when I delete one for example and add another one. I would load one picture with no source and it wouldn't loud the last picture because it wouldn't loop untill that one.

Comment: Can you post some of your code so we can help you? I suspect you should be looping from 0.

Comment: -1. Too vague. "It gives me an error" is not enough. Post your Code. Post your XAML. Post the exception or whatever error you get. At least try to simulate you're interested in resolving it and not having someone resolve it for you.

Comment: If updated my post with some code, I got a bit further ahead but I still can't the image to show, maby something to do with my path?

Answer (score 1):

The following using RX works for me.

Xaml

```
<Image Grid.Row="1" Source="{Binding AppViewModel.MainImageSource}"  Width="400" Stretch="Uniform"  Margin="{StaticResource MarginNormalControl}" />
```

View model:

```
SlideshowImages = ( from path in Directory.EnumerateFiles( pathSlideshow )
                    select new Uri( path ) ).ToList();
if ( SlideshowImages.Any() )
{ 
    SlideshowIndex = 0;
    var timer = Observable.Interval( TimeSpan.FromSeconds( 2 ) ).TimeInterval();
    timer.Subscribe( _ =>
                 {
                     ++SlideshowIndex;
                     if ( SlideshowIndex >= SlideshowImages.Count() )
                         SlideshowIndex = 0;
                     MainImageSource = SlideshowImages[SlideshowIndex];
                 } );
}
```

Comment: Strange, for some reason, my xaml doesn't show <Image Grid.Row="1"
         Source="{Binding AppViewModel.MainImageSource}"
         Width="400"
         Stretch="Uniform"
         Margin="{StaticResource MarginNormalControl}" />

Comment: Is appViewModel your controller file ?

Comment: It's a 'child' view model. Not sure what you mean by controller in WPF. Ignore that and just imagine a property as follows (I'm using RXUI, so ignore the code in the set{}.         Uri _MainImageSource = null;
        public Uri MainImageSource
        {
            get { return _MainImageSource; }
            set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(value); }
        }

Comment: I get this error

Error 1 'IntroScreen' does not contain a definition for 'RaiseAndSetIfChanged' and no extension method 'RaiseAndSetIfChanged' accepting a first argument of type 'IntroScreen' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: As I said, I'm using a MVVM library ReactiveUI, you'll want to use your own MVVM library for the set{} code to notify property change to update bound properties. This is answered in many places on SO. Here's one example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8062436/inotifypropertychanged-in-wpf