# How do you handle enable/disable support for non-ICommand bound Controls?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

On my view I have different Controls. Mostly `Button`s, `TextBox`es and `ComboBox`es. The Buttons are enabled/disabled via CommandBinding (`ICommand`), but the other controls must be enabled/disabled "manually". I can think of many ways to achieve this:

Adding a `bool`-Property to the ViewModel is one way and using `DataTriggers` is an other. (Or maybe I could bind the Property directly and use a `IValueConverter`.)

Is there a particular solution in MVVM that I am leaving out or missing?

Comment: You are dancing around it, but I don't think you are mentioning implementing INotifyPropertyChanged and just binding View properties to your ViewModel (MVVM). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx You can roll your own or use one of several good MVVM frameworks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8062436/inotifypropertychanged-in-wpf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can bind a public boolean property on your view model to the `IsEnabled` property of the control. There is no need for a value converter.

Comment: I know how to do that and I already done that in other Applications. I’m just asking because I don’t know which way to use/which is the  most “MVVM-ish” way.

Comment: binding to a public property of the view model that returns boolean is the mvvm way of doing it.  You can even bind the IsEnabled to the CanExecute function that your command uses.  devdigital is right

Comment: That's about as MVVM as you can get. It involves a view and a view model. You may even delegate a call from the view model down to the model, or expose the model on the view model directly to the view (depending on your priority of the DRY and LoD principles). That's got all the letters covered.

Comment: Ok, then I have to add a bool Property for every Control(or group of Controls with the same condition).

Thanks